# Ruby: Calling a method from another method that needs an attribute

Tags: ruby, class, oop, methods, arguments

Basically, I have two methods and an array.  I am setting up a CLI interface.  I have one method 'call' which runs through the other methods.  One such method needs an argument.  All of these methods are in the same class.

```
class CLI

  array = ["test"]

  def method_2
    method_1
  end

  def method_1(array)
    puts array
  end

end
```

I would like the above to output the array.  But, I get wrong number of arguments when I call a new instance of the class.  I can't figure out where to add the needed arguments.

Thank you for your time.

-M

Comment: `method_1` needs an argument, so your call of `method_1` in `method_2` is wrong. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I have several methods that I will need to call from 'method_2' but I need to figure out how to call one method first.  I would like method_2 to call method_1, and for method_1 to display the array (or any other variable)

Comment: What is `array = ["test"]` supposed to be? A constant? An instance variable? A class variable?

Comment: just a string as a placeholder.  I'm sorry, I'm new to this.  I didn't think it was important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in object oriented design you encapsulate the data and methods that act on the data in an object. In Ruby you create properties of an object by using instance variables:

```
class CLI
  def initialize(array = [])
    @array = []
  end

  def method_2
    method_1
  end

  def method_1
    puts @array
  end
end

cli = CLI.new(["Hello", "World"])
cli.method2
```

Instance variables use the sigil `@`. They are considered private since they are scoped to the instance even if Ruby does not use the `private` keyword for instance variables.

Classes can also have instance variables:

```
class CLI
  @array = ["Hello", "World"]

  def self.hello
    puts @array.join(" ")
  end

  def you_cant_access_it_from_an_instance
    @array
  end
end

CLI.hello # Hello World
CLI.new.you_cant_access_it_from_an_instance # nil
```

This is an "class" instance variable which belongs to the class itself - its not shared with subclasses. This works since in Ruby classes are objects - instances of the Class class.

Ruby also has class variables which are shared between a class and all its decendents:

```
class Foo

  @@array = ["Hello", "World"]
    
  def self.hello
    puts @@array.join(" ")
  end

  def self.array=(val)
    @@array = val
  end
end

class Bar < Foo; end
Bar.array = ['Oh', 'noes']
Foo.hello # Oh noes
```

They have serious issues with thread safety and are best avoided due to the unexpected behavior.

A common pattern for what I belive you are doing is a factory method that creates a new instance with its input and then calls its call method:

```
class CLI
  def initialize(*args)
    @args = args
  end

  def call
     puts @args.inspect
     # do something awesome
  end

  # factory method thats basically just a convenience
  def self.call(*args)
    new(args).call
  end
end

CLI.call(*ARGV) # passes the command line arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what it is that you're trying to do, but it sounds like what you want is to have at least one (or more) of your methods to print out the current value of a variable, but you don't want to pass that variable as an argument to those methods when you call them.

You can't accomplish that by defining a default argument (e.g. `def method_1(array=['test'])` because that default argument is only evaluated once when the method is defined, and that default value will forever be whatever it was when the method was first defined (it doesn't get updated).

So change your code to read like this:

```ruby
class CLI

  @@array = ["test"]

  def method_2
    method_1
  end

  def method_1
    puts @@array
  end

end
```

The `@@` prefix signifies a class variable: all instances of the class will share the same value of that variable.  Then you make sure that the value of `@@array` is kept up-to-date.  You may want to redesign your program, but barring matters of style and best practices, there's an answer for you.

The normal way of doing this is to just pass the argument to `method_1` when you call it, but if you want `method_2` to call `method_1` and you don't want to pass it as an argument to `method_2`, then you're kind of out of options (which is why I say you may want to redesign your interface).